# Controlled Natural Language scheme for describing system architectures?

Tags: architecture, uml, nlp, semantic-web

Are there any good Controlled Natural Language models, written in something like W3C Metalog PNL, for describing system architectures?

I'm looking for a text-based alternative to UML diagrams... to represent System Components, Relationships, Dependencies, Use Cases, Data Flows, etc. The goal is to have a model that can be programatically queried (unlike a diagram) to answer simple questions like, "what other components connect to this component?".

Thanks

Comment: I've never heard of one, but this would be horribly useful. :D

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "model" and "scheme". To make it clear, maybe you could rephrase your question and/or add an example.

Answer (score -2):

The answer to your question is probably *no*.

But if you have an existing model (e.g. a UML file) and you are able to save it as OWL, then you can load this OWL file into a tool like [ACE View](http://attempto.ifi.uzh.ch/aceview/) which verbalizes it in controlled English (ACE) and lets you query and edit it also in controlled English.

Comment: I don't have a model... I guess that's what I meant by "scheme"